# Display Leaflet circleMarker on top of other markers?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, markers

I have a `circleMarker` that I would like to display on top of all other markers. 
The [marker documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#marker) lists the option `zIndexOffset`, however `circleMarker` does not have this attribute.

`circleMarker` *does* inherit the `pane` option from `layer`, so I thought I could set the marker pane to `overlayPane` but that is already the default. (see [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#circlemarker-pane))

I can change the z-index of `overlayPane` but then all the other feature layers using it will share the same z-index.

Is there a simple way to display a `circleMarker` on top of other markers/layers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution I found is to create a custom pane for the circle marker and then set the z-index on that pane:

```
map.createPane("locationMarker");
map.getPane("locationMarker").style.zIndex = 999;
locationMarker = L.circleMarker(e.latlng, { pane: "locationMarker" });
locationMarker.addTo(map);
```